# Filtered listview highlighting incorrect item

Tags: android, listview, filter, selection

I have a list view where I am filtering items through a SearchView. On activating the state for an item, it is not getting the correct item instead getting it from the position. To make it more clear, please refer to the below screenshots:

1. Search for keyword com and selected the filtered item (i.e activated_state)

[image]

2. On clearing the filter, when the position of the items changes it does not keep track of the selected item i.e **com.android.gesture.builder**:

[image]

I want the selection to be correct regardless of the position change.

My code in MainActivity for this section:

```
 apps.setChoiceMode(apps.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
        apps.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {


                if (apps.isItemChecked(position)) {


                    Adapter.getItem(position);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CHECKED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    count = count + 1;
                    mode.setTitle(count + "items selected");


                    list_apps.add(Adapter.filteredData.get(position).packageName);



                    list_apps.trimToSize();

                }

                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "UNCHECKED" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    count--;
                    mode.setTitle(count + "items selected");

                    list_apps.remove(Adapter.filteredData.get(position).packageName);


                    list_apps.trimToSize();

                }
```

I am using an extended baseAdapter, please let me know if you need to see that code as well.

Update:

I am having OnItemClick listener in the code:

```
    apps.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                                    long arg3) {
/*
                for (int i = 0; i < packageList.size(); i++) {
                    TextView txtview = ((TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.textView1));

                    product = txtview.getText().toString();

                    list_apps.add(Adapter.filteredData.get(arg2).packageName);



                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, product,
                    //      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //for
                }
                */
                String selection;
                selection = Adapter.filteredData.get(arg2).packageName;

                 string = (String) Adapter.getItem(arg2);

                //list_apps.trimToSize();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, selection,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

                                                         I am using activated_state for the item selected on filtering and maintaining that selection.
```

Answer (score 0):

If i am not getting wrong, then you need to use OnItemClick lisenter, and get item like this.

Search View Change position of list item, but when we fetch our item from adapter, it return currect item.

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
   {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,
            long arg3) 
      {
            SString itemName = (String) adapter.getAdapter().getItem(position);

            // assuming string and if you want to get the value on click of list item
            // do what you intend to do on click of listview row
      }
   });
```

Comment: Hi Himanshu, I have added the update on OnItemClick in the original post at the very bottom. i am using activated_state which let me select multiple items in the list view.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function getVisibleArray() in your adapter, and call it from your onItemClickListener.

in setOnClickListener:

`People personInFocus = (People) adapter.getVisibleArray().get(position);`

And in adapter:

`public ArrayList<People> getVisibleArray() {
        return mDisplayedValues;
    }`

Which is your filtered array.

Ive tested it and it works.